# A closed set $A\subset Y$ is closed on $Y$ iff $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be a quotient space of X and $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a quotient function.

How to prove the following: A closed set $A\subset Y$ is closed on $Y$ iff $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed on $X$.

My attempt: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $A\subset Y$ is closed on $Y$. Then $Y-A$ is open on $Y$. How $\pi$ is the quotient function, $\pi^{-1}(Y-A)=\pi^{-1}(Y)-\pi{-1}(A)=X-\pi^{-1}(A)$ is open on $X \Leftrightarrow \pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed on $X$.

It's fine? How to prove the other inclusion?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characteristics of a quotient map $\pi:X\to Y$ are:

- $\pi$ is continuous.
- $\pi$  is surjective.
- If the preimage of $A\subseteq Y$ wrt to $\pi$ is open then $A$ is open.

From the fact that $\pi$ is continuous it follows that $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed whenever $A\subseteq Y$ is closed.

(That is the part you proved yourself. Only continuity is used there).

For the other side: if $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed then its complement is open, and this with: $$\pi^{-1}(A)^{\complement}=\pi^{-1}(A^{\complement})$$From the fact that $\pi^{-1}(A^{\complement})$ is open we conclude that $A^{\complement}$ is an open set, hence $A$ is a closed set.

---

remark:

The third characteristic can also be interchanged by:

- If the preimage of $A\subseteq Y$ wrt to $\pi$ is closed then $A$ is closed.

Comment: You are very welcome.